# How can I save a image which is on local?

Tags: php, image

I have this script which generates an image:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(110, 34);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 245, 245, 245);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 80, 80, 80);
imagestring($im, 8, 15, 9, image, $text_color);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
```

Now I want to save that image. How can I do that? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
file_put_contents("../img/name.jpg", file_get_contents($im));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: all you need to do is pass another parameter to `imagejpeg($im,$filename)`

Comment: Put `file_put_contents("../img/name.jpg", $im)` before your `header()` statement

Comment: @Octopus Your comment solved my problem *(which I was stuck on it for two days)*

Comment: @Octopus Also I don't need that header, hum? am I right? Because I don't want to see that image, I just want to save it.